# Magento programmatically get discount giving coupon code and products

Tags: magento, coupon

I'm trying to integrate a system with Magento, I would like a way to send the coupon code, current user and cart to Magento and retrieve the according discount (if applies), so I don't have to replicate all the logic behind coupon validation.

I would really appreciate it.

I managed to do the following.

```
    $customerId = 1;
    $couponCode = "TESTCOUPON";
    $json = "{
                \"cart\":[{
                    \"listProduct\":[{
                        \"idReferenceProduct\":15,
                        \"quantity\":1
                    }]
                }]
            }";
    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);
    $products = $jsonDecoded->cart[0]->listProduct;

    // *********************************************************

    $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    $storeId = $customerObj->getStoreId();
    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
    $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($storeId);
    $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj); 

    foreach ($products as $singleProduct) {

        $productObj =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productObj->load($singleProduct->idReferenceProduct);
        echo $productObj->getName();
        echo $productObj->getPrice();

        try{
            $quoteItem = $quoteObj->addProduct($productObj);
            $quoteItem->setPrice($productObj->getPrice());
            $quoteItem->setQty($singleProduct->quantity);
            $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);                                    
            $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);

        } catch (exception $e) {
            echo "error creating quote item ";
        }

        $singleProduct->quantity);
    }

    try{
        $quoteObj->setCouponCode($couponCode); 
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        return "error setting coupon";
    }

    $quoteObj->collectTotals();

    var_dump($quoteObj->toArray());
```

And the output:

```
{
["customer_id"] = > "1" 
["customer_prefix"] = > NULL
["customer_firstname"] = > "xxxxxx" 
["customer_middlename"] = > NULL
["customer_lastname"] = > "xxxxxxx" 
["customer_suffix"] = > NULL
["customer_email"] = > "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" 
["customer_dob"] = > "1981-03-06 00:00:00" 
["customer_taxvat"] = > NULL
["customer_gender"] = > "1" 
["customer_group_id"] = > "1" 
["customer_tax_class_id"] = > "3" 
["store_id"] = > "1" 
["coupon_code"] = > "TESTCOUPON"
["subtotal"] = > float(872.06)
["base_subtotal"] = > float(872.06)
["subtotal_with_discount"] = > float(830.92)
["base_subtotal_with_discount"] = > float(830.92)
["grand_total"] = > float(929.64)
["base_grand_total"] = > float(929.64)
["applied_rule_ids"] = > "1" 
["virtual_items_qty"] = > int(0)
["taxes_for_items"] = > {
    [""] = > {
        [0] = > {
            ["rates"] = > {
                [0] = > {
                    ["code"] = > "IVA" 
                    ["title"] = > "IVA" 
                    ["percent"] = > float(12)
                    ["position"] = > "1" 
                    ["priority"] = > "1" 
                    ["rule_id"] = > "1"
                }
            }["percent"] = > float(12)
            ["id"] = > "IVA"
        }
    }
}["items_count"] = > int(2)
["items_qty"] = > float(2)
["trigger_recollect"] = > int(0)
["can_apply_msrp"] = > bool(false)
["totals_collected_flag"] = > bool(true)
}
```

The coupon discount is supposed to be a 5% discount.

For some reason the prices are not correct. That product price is 516.00 and the subtotal in the output states 872.06. Also there's only one item and the output states 2 items. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement ? Actually I am not getting your point.

Comment: In short I need to create a method that receives coupon code, cart and customer and returns discount amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, it seems I was adding the products to the quote the wrong way. This is the way it works now:

```
        $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $quoteItem->setProduct($productObj);
        $quoteItem->setPrice($productObj->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setQty($singleProduct->quantity);
        $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);                                    
        $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
```

Comment: I have this situation too and I came up with a similar implementation as yours. My scripts also returns the grand_total of the quote. However there is a issue with this kind of technique. I have coupon codes that are valid for only 1 "Use per Customer". So, when I run my script the coupon is used up and will no longer be available for the particular user. 

My application works by first calling this aforementioned script. Shows the grand total to user and then calls another script that actually places the order.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue ?